# How to connect wires to multiple Pads?

Tags: connector, multiplexer

Not sure if this is the right community - please tell me if it isn't.

I have a connector (see image below) to contact pads of a sample and connected them to a multiplexer. I want to replicate it.

[image: Connections am trying to replicate]

Howver the new samples I need to contact have a different pad distances with **pitch new =0.83mm** vs pitch old = 0.80. Therefore I want to make a new connector with:

- d1 = 1.66 mm
- d2=  3.00 mm

[image: Pattern for connections]

To make it, i think i need:

- Crimped wires on one side - on the otehr soldered to the loaded tips
- Spring loaded tips
- wire housing
- the crimped end of the wires  end into this structure (see image below) -  **What is the name of this thing to buy it?**
  [image: Crimped wires ending]

1. What is the name of the thing the crimped wires are ending in (so i can buy it)
2. Is there companies/ services that make spring tip connections with set distance, or something similar?
3. What materials are missing form this list, if I wanted to make it?
4. What improvements could be made to the design to make it easier?

Comment: for 1, you want to search for "dupont connector housing" (note: they aren't all made by the company Dupont but they should have dupont as a search keyword). But your first picture doesn't actually have one of these housings. It looks like the wires are directly soldered to the spring-loaded pins which are inserted into a custom plastic part (which you could 3d-print)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a service or a simpler way of doing this? this was done from a post-doc some years ago, but connecting with spring loaded tips with set distances seems like something that could be achieved in an easier way that custom build

Comment: Any time you have specific distances, that screams "custom build" - unless you can find a standard part with those distances already. But it doesn't have to be too difficult. Imagine sticking the pins in some kind of prototyping material with the consistency of cheese - you could just stick them in and wiggle them around to line them up. (I don't know what that material would be. I don't recommend cheese, it'll go moldy)

Comment: I'll remember not to use cheese. Do you know where i can buy these half-crimped wires. I cant find them with "crimped wires".

Comment: Just get wires crimped on both ends, and cut them in the middle

Comment: You can buy the idc cable and the crimps separate. Or buy crimped cable and strip one side.

Comment: And you can get these made for a small fee. https://www.makerfabs.com/testing-jig-fixture-customizing-service.html

Comment: @user253751 is there a typicall ditance for pinns i can use? I could ask someone to fabricate a standardize sping connector for future projecs

Comment: @leoelectrics how would that help? you already have two devices here with different distances

Comment: @user253751 It wouldn't for this Batch, but I could ask the Fabrication facility to use different specs for the new mask.